# Find the GCD of $2^{60}-1$ and $2^{50}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

My teacher said we can solve this using Euclid's division lemma but I have no clue how. I factored the numbers into
$$2^{60}-1 = (2^{10}-1)(1+2^{10}+2^{20}+...+2^{50})$$
and
$$2^{50}-1 = (2^{10}-1)(1+2^{10}+2^{20}+...+2^{40})$$
So I got the gcd as $2^{10}-1$. But I don't know if there can be some common factor in
$(2^{10}-1)(1+2^10+2^{20}+...+2^{40})$ and $(2^{10}-1)(1+2^{10}+2^{20}+...+2^{50})$.

Comment: Hint : The gcd must also divide $2^{60}-2^{50}$, the difference of the numbers.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1